# Cannot load Node native addons with webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, node-modules, webpack-4, node.js-addon

Although I am using `vue-cli` in the example code to generate a webpack config, nothing is specific to vue.

I create the example app like this:

`vue init webpack webpack_modules_example`

Generated `webpack.base.conf`:

```js
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const config = require('../config')
const vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      'ad-block': 'ad-block/build/Release/ad-block.node',
      '@': resolve('src'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  node: {
    setImmediate: false,
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty'
  }
}
```

I want to include [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ad-block), so I do this:

`npm install --save ad-block`

And on the code (`App.vue`) I add this:

```
<script>
...
  const {AdBlockClient, FilterOptions} = require('ad-block')
...
```

Because it's a native module, I need to install some loader for webpack (tried several):

`npm install native-ext-loader --save-dev`

Add the loader to the webpack config:

```
  {
    test: /\.node$/,
    loader: "native-ext-loader"
  },
```

And create an alias in the webpack config too:

```
alias: {
      ...
      'ad-block': 'ad-block/build/Release/ad-block.node',
      ...
    }
```

But when I run `npm run dev` and go to http://localhost:8080/
I see this error in the console:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot open /ad-block.node: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dlopen' of undefined
>
> at Object.eval (ad-block.node?9538:1)
>
> at eval (ad-block.node:2)
>
> at Object../node_modules/ad-block/build/Release/ad-block.node (app.js:733)
>
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:679)
>
> at fn (app.js:89)
>
> at eval (App.vue?26cd:9)
>
> at Object../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue (app.js:757)
>
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:679)
>
> at fn (app.js:89)
>
> at eval (App.vue?a8e9:1)

If I use this without webpack, it works. Not sure what am I missing!

Comment: You can't use node native libraries in client applications. First of all, it's insecure, second - it should be compiled/build for each platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NodeJS is a server-side programming environment and as such, supports “native” add-on modules compiled to run on the same host that runs your Node service.

While Node is programmed using JavaScript, it is not browser JavaScript and so native ad-ons cannot be expected to run in the browser.

See [Node C++ Addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) for more information.